# A question on the formulation of core-shell quantum dot Boundary conditions in K.P method

Tags: quantum-mechanics, wavefunction, boundary-conditions

When studying the energy levels of core-shell quantum dots with eight-band k.p method, an important part is the formulation of boundary conditions for wavefunctions. In the Supporting Information of the paper: 
http://pubs.acs.org/doi/suppl/10.1021/acs.nanolett.6b00066/suppl_file/nl6b00066_si_001.pdf

the authors (Roman Vaxenburg et al.) summarized this as below

[image: screen shot of the Support Information]

However, I have difficulty in understanding the concept of the vectorial valence-band envelope function $\Psi_v$ here. We know that wavefunction is a scalar, not a vector, while the above equations seem to indicate that $\Psi_v$ is a vector. So my question is: 
How do we interpret this vectorial wavefunction? 
In fact, this question might be trivial for people in the field. In case anyone is familiar with the calculation of quantum levels of core-shell quantum dot with eight-band k.p method, would you please help me out with this issue?  Thanks!

Comment: I thought wave functions were like infinite dimensional vectors? And then to compute complex ones you expanded in a finite basis like Hartree-Fock. This is slightly outside my knowledge of QM though so not sure if I'm wrong.

Comment: Thank you very much, while I thought the vector adopted here was a math-trick. So my point is: How do we interpret the basis vector here?                       This question might be clear for someone who familiar with eight-band k.p method

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The wave function *is* a scalar quantity. However, it is often convenient to expand it in other bases. k.p theory can be understood intuitively as follows. The energy bands in a crystal are described by Bloch functions. According to the Bloch theorem and in the single particle picture, you can write the wave function, $\psi_e(\mathbf{r})$, of an electron in the conduction band as
\begin{equation}
\psi_e(\mathbf{r}) = u_{e,\mathbf{k}}(\mathbf{r})\mathrm{e}^{i\mathbf{k}\cdot\mathbf{r}},
\end{equation}
where $\mathbf{k}$ is the wave vector of the electron. It can be shown that the Bloch functions belonging to all the energy bands in the solid (at a specific $\mathbf{k}$-point) form a complete and orthogonal basis set.

It is thus convenient to expand the (unknown) wavefunction of the quantum dot into the basis set created by the Bloch functions in bulk. And since all the action happens at the $\Gamma$ point in optics (i.e., $\mathbf{k}=0$), one can thus write
for, e.g., the hole wave function
\begin{equation}
\psi_{h,\mathrm{QD}}(\mathbf{r}) = \sum_{i=1}^\infty u_{i,\mathbf{0}}(\mathbf{r})\Psi_{i}(\mathbf{r}),
\end{equation}
where $\Psi_i(\mathbf{r})$ are the expansion coefficients, also called slowly varying envelopes. As you can see, the quantum-dot wave function, $\psi_{h,\mathrm{QD}}(\mathbf{r})$, inherits the properties of all the bands in the unperturbed crystal. In practice, this infinite sum can be truncated because $\Psi_{i}(\mathbf{r})$ are significant for a couple of $i$-s only. This is because the hole wave function, $\psi_{h,\mathrm{QD}}(\mathbf{r})$, is not perturbed significantly compared to bulk and thus inherits most of the properties from a few bands nearby in energy. In 8x8 k.p theory, you consider three valence bands (because the valence-band states inherit the symmetry of the $p_{x,y,z}$ orbitals and are thus three-fold degenerate) and one conduction band. So 4 bands in total but if you include spin then it's 8 (hence 8x8). You can thus write the slowly varying envelope of the hole wave function as
\begin{equation}
\vec{\Psi_{h,\mathrm{QD}}} = (\Psi_x, \Psi_y, \Psi_z, \Psi_e) = (\vec{\Psi_v},\Psi_e),
\end{equation}
In reality, you also include spin, see for instance https://journals.aps.org/prb/pdf/10.1103/PhysRevB.67.155312 . I hope this helps.